# merge an array by parent id using lodashjs api

Tags: arrays, lodash

I have an array with structure as below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "SUB",
    "username": "jksub04m1s8"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "type": "SUB",
    "username": "jksub04m2s4"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "type": "OPERATOR",
    "username": "mountbetoperator"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "type": "SUB",
    "username": "jksub04m2s2"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "type": "SUB",
    "username": "jksub04m1s8"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "type": "SUB",
    "parent_id": 2,
    "username": "jksub04m1s8"
  }
]
```

I write an function to restructure it by mapping it parent id as below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "SUB",
    "username": "jksub04m1s8",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "type": "SUB",
        "username": "jksub04m2s4",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "type": "SUB",
            "username": "jksub04m2s2"
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "type": "SUB",
            "parent_id": 2,
            "username": "jksub04m1s8"
          }
        ]
      }...
]
```

But my function is so long and make the process so slow, actually I have about 10000+ records like this.

Could I use lodash api to restructure it?

Comment: If performance is concern, better not to use lodash, just for handling all the corner cases it will iterate to many times, you can write a simple function in plain js to make it more performance efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply right a JS function, using a map and iterate the array twice you can achieve this, you don't even need recursive function or complex code. here is a example I have written you can try.

```js
var arr = arr = [{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "SUB",
        "username": "jksub04m1s8"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "type": "SUB",
        "username": "jksub04m2s4"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "type": "OPERATOR",
        "username": "mountbetoperator"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "parent_id": 2,
        "type": "SUB",
        "username": "jksub04m2s2"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "type": "SUB",
        "username": "jksub04m1s8"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "type": "SUB",
        "parent_id": 2,
        "username": "jksub04m1s8"
    }
];

function transform(input) {
    var res = [],
        idx,
        map = {},
        addedToParentMap = {},
        temp,
        tempParent,
        curr,
        twiceLen = input.length * 2;
    for (idx = 0; idx < twiceLen; idx++) {
        curr = input[idx % input.length];
        temp = map[curr.id] || Object.assign({
            children: []
        }, curr);

        if (!temp.parent_id && !map[curr.id]) {
            res.push(temp);
        } else {
            tempParent = map[temp.parent_id];
            if (tempParent && !addedToParentMap[temp.id]) {
                tempParent.children.push(temp);
                addedToParentMap[temp.id] = true;
            }
        }
        map[curr.id] = temp;
    }
    return res;
}

var res = transform(arr);
console.log(res);
```